# std::initializer_list alternatives for noncopyable types

Tags: c++, c++11, list-initialization

I know that trying to use a `std::initializer_list<NonCopyable>` leads to an error because the elements are copied into the temporary array represented by the `initializer_list`. I have also read some explanation on why it would not be alright to have rvalue references in the list, which I'm fine with.

The problem is that I would like to pass noncopyable things not in order to move from them, but only `const`-access them, so the argument about rvalues does not apply. What can I do to retain, if possible, the list initialization syntax and the reference semantics (no wrappers, no raw pointers)?

```
NonCopyable a{...}, b{...};
ListInitialized c{a, b};
```

I think I'm missing something extremely obvious here.

**Update:**

This works(*),

```
ListInitialized(std::initializer_list<std::reference_wrapper<NonCopyable>>) {...}
```

but won't accept rvalues. It would be nice if I could simply pass a list of anything that could go into `const NonCopyable&`.

<sub>(*) I know I wrote "no wrappers" but this affects neither the calling code nor the iteration over the list.</sub>

Comment: I may have misunderstood something, but why not simply `std::initializer_list<std::reference_wrapper<const NonCopyable>>`?

Comment: @MichaelKenzel `const` or not, it won't accept `ListInitialized c{NonCopyable{...}}`. If `T` was copyable, I could freely use existing objects of type `T` or immediately created ones or mix and match.

Comment: Indeed, I forgot that `std::reference_wrapper` prevents you from using it with rvalue references. You could roll your own conversion helper function, e.g., `std::reference_wrapper<const T> cref(T&& r) { return r; }` and then do `ListInitialized { cref(NonCopyable{...}) }`. But I would probably just go with the approach described by Angew below…

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can give `ListInitialized` a variadic constructor template:

```
struct ListInitialized
{
  template <class... T>
  ListInitialized(const T... &arg);
};
```

If you need to make sure it can only be instantiated with the correct type, consider suitable [SFINAE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SFINAE):

```
struct ListInitialized
{
  template <
    class... T,
    class Sfinae = std::enable_if_t<std::is_same<std::decay_t<T>, NonCopyable> &&...
  >
  ListInitialized(const T... &arg);
};
```

Comment: Good approach! This somehow defeats the intent of `std::initializer_list`, though?

Comment: I think it will do nicely in my use case. I'm just afraid the price is possibly a lot of different instantiations generated if the number of elements tends to vary, so I'll wait if there's another alternative.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the comments and answers above, I found that this minimalistic wrapper fulfills my needs:

```cpp
#include <initializer_list>
#include <utility>

struct S {
  S() { }
  S(const S&) = delete; // Non-copyable
  void f() const { }
};

template<class T>
class const_reference_wrapper {
public:
  const_reference_wrapper(const T& ref_) : ref(ref_) { }
  operator const T&() const { return ref; }
private:
  const T& ref;
};

struct T {
  T(std::initializer_list<const_reference_wrapper<S>> l) : c(l.size()) {
    for(const S& i : l)  // note: const auto& can't be used here, but it would be the same for std::reference_wrapper
      i.f();  // we can do something with the elements
  }

  int c;
};

int main() {
  S a, b;
  T t{a, b, S{}};  // we can mix lvalues and rvalues with a natural syntax
  return t.c;  // correctly returns 3
}
```

Of course, care needs to be taken to ensure that any rvalue passed through this will live through the time it is being referenced.